# How to compute a state exhibiting a given entanglement entropy?

Tags: entropy, quantum-entanglement, many-body, ads-cft

We`ve known how to calculate entanglement entropy from a given ground state: make an entanglement cut (that divide system into subsystems $A$ and $B$), take the partial trace and
$$S=-\operatorname{Tr}(\rho_A\cdot \log\rho_A).$$

But is it possible to start from entanglement entropy (ie: a function $S: \text{cuts} \rightarrow R$), as long as it is physical, to reconstruct a state that exhibits the entanglement pattern we demand?

Of course, there are examples that such a reconstruction will not be unique. But given knowledge of what local degrees of freedom are, is there any way to find at least one such state?

Any reference will be appreciated. And please feel free to edit my question if it is needed.

Comment: To clarify: Are you assuming a fixed factorization of the Hilbert space, as in
$$
\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{H}_1\otimes\mathcal{H}_2\otimes\cdots\otimes \mathcal{H}_N,
$$
and assuming that we are given the von Neumann entanglement entropy $S(\Omega)$ associated with every subset $\Omega$ of the factors? And then the question is how to construct an example of a single density matrix on $\mathcal{H}$ that is compatible with this set of $N$-choose-$2$ von Neumann entropies, when such a density matrix exists?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly yes. And physically I think the density matrix has to be a pure state corresponding to some ground state of an almost local Hamiltonian. But anyway, let`s see if it is generally possible.

Comment: *"reconstruct a state"* -- as long as you impose any conditions the state must satisfy: Obviously yes.  Otherwise, you will have to say which conditions (a) the entanglement spectrum satisfies (or whatever else -- do you only want to obtain a certain value for the entropy? for one/all/... cuts??) and (b) the bulk state should have.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch What I`m looking for is actually an algorithm that starts from entanglement and ends up with a certain state.

Comment: Like "The entanglement is 5, then the state must be this and that?"  How would that be possible???  Could you please clarify your question, either by being more specific or at least providing an illustrating example?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch suppose I have a 2-d system whose entanglement entropy satisfies the area law, ie: $S(cut)\propto perimeter\ of\ the\ cut$. Now the way to find such states is by constructing a tensor network (usually PEPS for gapped system and MERA for gapless) that describe the system and see how it incorporate with local degrees of freedom. My question that is in general, when the entanglement violates the area law, is there a similar algorithm to obtain such a state? Not necessarily every state possible, but find just one of them will do.

Comment: I still don't understand your question. What are you given, and what do you want to achieve?  (In particular, I can't reconcile your last comment with the question above.)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch The known information is the entanglement entropy corresponding to each bipartition: it may obey area law in some region and violate it in some other. What I want to find is such a state that when performed with an entanglement cut, gives entropy consistent with my known information(at least the same dependence). My comment above is an example of how it is made when the given information has certain pattern.

Comment: I see. I think it would help if you would make this more clear in the question. (E.g., what you mean by "entanglement pattern".) --- Clearly, if the entropies violate some entropy inequality then it is impossible.